# Remix passing props

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I have recently navigated to remix and am struggling passing props from route to route. I have a route 'Table.tsx' that sets the state of a prop. I have another route 'Interface.tsx' that contains the child component 'Populate.tsx'. I am trying to pass my prop from Table.tsx to Populate.tsx. what is the remix method to accomplish this? or should I be using a state management tool such as redux? I am using remix not react-router!

Comment: Just FYI, Remix and React-Router are basically the same thing. You still use `Link` components with a `state` prop, or a `useNavigate` hook with a `state` property, or you can pass data in the route path and access via the `useParams` hook, etc. The only difference may be what you import these components/hooks from, but the usage is exactly the same.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you. That then is the answer, that remix will handle it the same as react-router, but with different imports. I was not aware, as this is my first Remix project. Thanks again